# How to make the command line / terminal mirror the GUI?

Tags: command-line

When using the **GUI** and making **actions** I think that users would like to see how those *actions* are being **reflected** in the *terminal* using **command lines**.

I can imagine that there are different layers of commands/processes that could be reflected which are endless but lets keep it simple and in direct relation to the end user GUI experience.

**Examples:**

1. opening an applications such libreoffice or web browser...
2. browsing home folders and copy, cut, paste...
3. Network manager changes such as wireless up, down and wired up, down...
4. and so on...

This would satisfy curiosity and also help as a teaching/learning tool for those curious about the command line. Do others see this need? Does this already exist and if not would this be feasible for an end user teaching experience?

Comment: It doesn't work that way. And it would still be a bad way to learn how to use the terminal, because you would have to investigate about a billion buttons. :)

Answer (score 0):

Most of "GUI actions" don't really have a terminal equivalent, or have more than one. That's because most time GUIs don't really issue terminal commands, they issue system / kernel commands.

What you can do:

- with `dmesg` you can see "kernel messages", see http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue59/nazario.html
- For some softwares (with GUI), opening them from terminal will allow you to see some debug and various messages (info, notices, warnings)
- Check the software source code
- [Debug a software](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProcedures)